# How can I use an Angular injected service inside a table.on() function of datatables.net

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm using https://datatables.net/ on my Angular 9 App

I have a service inyected on my component, like this

```
constructor(private backOffice: BackofficeService) { }
```

Then I have a function on my ngAfterViewInit() that triggers when I click a  'like' button on my data table.

```
    table.on('click', '.like', function(e) {
      let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      console.log ($tr)
    }
```

What I want to do is to invoke my service inside this function in order call some method on my backoffice service in order to change some data in my database.
But the thing is, **'this'** in this case is not making reference to my component, is making reference to my table, so I can't use **this**.backOffice.myMethod().

What im trying to achieve, is somethin like this:

```
    table.on('click', '.like', function(e) {
      const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      const data = table.row($tr).data();
      THIS.backOffice.MyMethod(data)
      .subscribe ( response => {
            console.log (response)
      });
    }
```

How can I do that?

If this is not possible, My question is How can I get a $tr reference in my component.html to use a (click)="SomeOtherFunction(**$tr**)" in order to handle this action without the table.on() function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try as follow

```
const backOffice = this.backOffice;

table.on('click', '.like', function(e) {
      const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
      const data = table.row($tr).data();
      backOffice.MyMethod(data)
        .subscribe ( response => {
            console.log (response)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Radik, thanks for your help. I have tried that, and also `xxxComponent.backOffice.MyMethod` and still doesn't works =(

Comment: @Cristian check my example below line 50 https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-ngxs-datatables?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.module%2Fcomponents%2Fgrid-view%2Fgrid-view.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the help @Radik
As I saw in your example, I had forgotten to include this line  `const backOffice = this.backOffice;`  before calling the table.on function.
Now it works great !
Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the arrow function, so that this points to your current class, and retrieve the data table from the event

```
table.on('click', '.like', (e : any) => {
  const $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');
  const data = table.row($tr).data();
  this.MyMethod(data)
    .subscribe ( response => {
        console.log (response)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David ! That will be usefull too

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to a service inside of event, then you can refresh data of your data table by example:

Component

```
 this.homeService.getBookingAsync().then((response: any)=>{
      this.bookResponse = response;
      this.configDataTable.data = this.bookResponse.data.results; // add results
      var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
      table.clear().draw(); // clear current data in datatable
      table.rows.add(this.bookResponse.data.results); //set data to datatable
      table.columns.adjust().draw(); //draw new set data 
      Swal.close(); //ignore this
    });

Service 


public async getBookingAsync() {
    let filter  = this.constructGetUrl();
    filter = filter + this.setColumsToFilter();
    filter = filter + this.completeUrl(filter);
    let fullUrl = `${BASE_URL}/${API_URL}${filter}`;
    const result = await this.httpClient.get(fullUrl).toPromise(); // get with promise
    return result;
 }


DataTable Configuration

export class DataTableConfiguration {
  responsive :boolean;
  scrollY:string;
  scrollCollapse: boolean;
  data: any;
  columns:  any;
  pagingType: string;
  pageLength: number;
  processing: boolean;
  searching: boolean;
  dom: string;
  buttons:any;
  columnDefs:any;
}
```

I hope thats can help you .